# Line break for data detectors (url, email, phone number)

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have enabled data detectors in my UITextField to detect urls, email, phone numbers, and more (see image).

[image]

Sometimes it is hard to click a URL or phone number.  I was wondering there was an easy way to add a line break before and after an data detector types (url/number/email/etc) so that it is a little easier to touch.  How do I detect if a string is a data detector type?

Or, is there an better way to make the url tappable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set your attributed string on the textview, do the following:

```
//Change UIFont to your font and size
if let attributedString = textView.attributedText, let font =  UIFont(name: "YourFontName", size: 14) {

    let newString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)

    let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = [.link, .phoneNumber, .address, .date, .transitInformation]

    let linkDetector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
    let range = NSRange(location:0,length: attributedString.length)
    linkDetector?.enumerateMatches(in: attributedString.string, options: [], range: range, using: { 
        (match : NSTextCheckingResult?, flags : NSRegularExpression.MatchingFlags, stop) in

         if let matchRange = match?.range {
             newString.removeAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, range: matchRange)
             newString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: matchRange)
         }
    })

    textView.attributedText = newString
}
```